# Working with local Azure Storage Emulator with generated SAS URIs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

for local development with blob storage i used local storage emulator and now i need to develop connecting to blob storage through HTTP (via SAS URIs for uplaod/download).

For cloud storage it works how it should, but when i try to make HTTP requests to local Azure blob storage emulator with generated SAS URIs i always get 403 Forbidden response.

I tried setting CORS policy for blob containers, tables and queues to allow anything.

But nothing has helped.

How could I overcome this issue?

The error is:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.